# If $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin 2x) \, dx = k \int_{0}^{\pi/4} f(\cos x) \cos x \,dx$, find $k$.

Tags: definite-integrals

> Find $k$ such that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin 2x) \,dx =
> k \int_{0}^{\pi/4}f(\cos x) \cos x \,dx.$$

I applied the properties of DI , but am not able to change 
$\sin 2x$ into $\cos x$.

Comment: What properties of $f$ do you know, because without further information $k$ cannot be found.